# Saving txt files in a while loop saves the current and previous iteration at each step

Tags: python, file

I create a while loop to run a simulation for which I want 100 results. Every iteration generates two text files and appends another one, each for different results generated.

I am getting all of the results I expect to get, but at each iteration one of the generated files from the last iteration is saved again. It contains the same results as in the previous iteration, so I have no problem with that but would like to understand what's happening.

In the example below, `file_a` and `file_b` are generated the same way, but `file_b` is saved for the current and the previous iteration at each step.

Thanks for the help!

```py
while sum(1 for _ in open('appended_file.txt')) <= 101:
    with open('appended_file.txt') as f:
        xx = sum(1 for _ in f)

    # Several lines of code to generate the results

    # Appended file - no problem with this one
    results_out.to_csv('appended_file.txt', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', mode='a', header=False)

    # File a and b, with iteration written in file name
    file_a = open('file_a_' + str(xx) + '.txt', 'w')
    for item in data_a:
        file_a.write("%s\n" % item)

    # File b is saved at each iteration for the current and the previous iteration
    file_b = open('file_b' + str(xx) + '.txt', 'w')
    for item in data_b:
        file_b.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close your output files when you have finished writing to them.

The best approach is to use a similar `with` construct as what you used for reading the input file, because this ensures that the file is closed properly even if an exception is raised inside the block (for example if `item` could not be converted to a string).  When the `with` block completes, the file object is destroyed and the file is automatically closed.

```
    with open('file_a_' + str(xx) + '.txt', 'w') as file_a:
        for item in data_a:
            file_a.write("%s\n" % item)
```

but it would also work if you modify your code to call the `close` method explicitly:

```
    file_a = open('file_a_' + str(xx) + '.txt', 'w')
    for item in data_a:
        file_a.write("%s\n" % item)
    file_a.close()
```

If you do not close the file, then the file will remain open until the `file_a` variable is reassigned to a new file object during the next iteration, at which point there will be no more references to the previous file object so the object will be destroyed and the previous file automatically closed.  Until that time, the file contents might not be complete, because output data can be buffered until the file is closed.

Similarly for `file_b`.